# Zend Framework gets trapped in exception, no way back

Tags: zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'm building an api with apigility over a symfony2 app. After a runtime error in symfony2 app which led to an exception in zend, every call from zend (the error is now solved) leads to the same exception.

The error I think is actually not relavant but here it is:

> "[Semantical Error] The annotation \"@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity\" in class App\UserBundle\Entity\Usuario does not exist

Is there a cache system or similar stuff in zend framework or apigility that I can flush to clean this error?

Thank you

Comment: not sure which cache are you talking about, but usually if is a webservice for example you should clear your temporary folder on linux /tmp

Comment: It turned out to be Symfony 'prod' cache